# List comprehension for loops Python

Tags: python, inline, list-comprehension

I use a lot of N dimensional arrays and it gets a pain to have to write such indented code and I know some codes can be replaced with list comprehensions and inline statements. For example:

```
for x in (0,1,2,3):
    for y in (0,1,2,3):
        if x < y:
            print (x, y, x*y)
```

can be replaced with:

```
print [(x, y, x * y) for x in (0,1,2,3) for y in (0,1,2,3) if x < y]
```

But how could I change the action instead of print to do something else like:

```
total = x+y
```

So what I want to do is something like:

```
[(total+=x+y) for x in (0,1,2,3) for y in (0,1,2,3) if x < y]
```

However this doesn't work

Is there a smart way to do this rather than:

```
for x in (0,1,2,3):
        for y in (0,1,2,3):
            if x < y:
                total+=x+y
```

Comment: how about you use a better editor, that does the intendation for you, since that seems to be your actual problem. In my opinion the original code you posted as example is the one that is the most easiest to read.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sum` works here:

```
total = sum(x+y for x in (0,1,2,3) for y in (0,1,2,3) if x < y)
```

Comment: This is the easiest to comprehend solution by far.

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative to writing loops N levels deep, you could use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
In [1]: import itertools as it

In [2]: for x, y in it.product((0,1,2,3),(0,1,2,3)):
   ...:     if x < y:
   ...:         print x, y, x*y

0 1 0
0 2 0
0 3 0
1 2 2
1 3 3
2 3 6
```

This extends naturally to N dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

Use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). This lets you use arrays that add up like vectors:

```
x = numpy.arange(3)
y = numpy.arange(3)
total = x + y
```

With the modified question, add a call to `sum` as well

```
total = numpy.sum(x+y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce function directly reduces collective items to single item. You can [read more about them here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node83.html), but this should work for you:

```
total=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,range(4))
```

or

```
total=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,(0,1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is:

```
for x,y in ((x,y) for x in (0,1,2,3) for y in (0,1,2,3) if x < y):
  print (x, y, x * y)
```

In this way you can iterate over anything you'd use in a list comprehension without actually creating the comprehended list (if you get my meaning ;) If comprehended list is big, maybe so big it saturates or even doesn't fit in memory, that's quite handy..