# JSON and Django fields

Tags: json, django

What is the best way of storing a dictionary within Django. Is there a native way of pushing the entire JSON into a field or should I try using something else...what do people recommend. I'd like to keep as standard Django as possible.

Comment: I'm using MySQL by the way

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answer, please accept it and vote it up. Also, you should do the same for your "[gold question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847624/list-comprehension-for-loops-python)"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PostgreSQL, you may look at [django-hstore](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-hstore)

```
class Something(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    data = hstore.DictionaryField()  # can pass attributes like null, blank, ecc.

instance = Something.objects.create(name='something', data={'a': '1', 'b': '2'})
assert instance.data['a'] == '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no special JSON datatype for MySQL. At one of my job, we used a normal text/blob field. Before writing it in the DB, we compact it:

```
>>> json.dumps([1,2,3,{'4': 5, '6': 7}], separators=(',',':'))
'[1,2,3,{"4":5,"6":7}]'
```

And when we need to show it (if you ever need to show it?), we pretty print it:

```
>>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True,
...                  indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

These snippets come from the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: Thanks. What do you find works best blob or simple textfield?

Comment: Text. `blob` is usually for things like images, binaries etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several packages which support JSON fields on models: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/json-fields/

There's one MySQL specific also: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html